# Backbone Popblock click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to get a click handler to open a Facebook Login window using backbone but the click event is registering as a popup and being blocked by the browser.

My click event it calling an external function facebookStatus() which has the FBlogin.

Any idea how I can bind the Fblogin to the click event using my setup below?

**Main.js**

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

el : "#main",
model: false,
shareModel: false,

events: {
  'click #fblogin' : 'onClick',

},

onClick: function(e) {

  var self = this;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (typeof (FB) != "undefined") {

    $(".social-login").html("Por favor espera...");
    facebookStatus(self.model);

  } else {
    alert("Please wait Facebook APP is ready");
  }

  return false;
}
```

});

**facebookSDK.js**

```
function facebookStatus(model) {


var data = new Object();
data.action = "login";

var display = 'popup';
var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
console.log(iOS);
if (iOS) {
  display = 'touch';
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status=="connected"){
      console.log("7");
      data.token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      model.fetch({data:data,type:'POST'});
    }
  }, {scope: 'user_about_me,user_likes'});

}};
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">    
  <div class="social-login">
        <a id="fblogin" href="javascript;">
            <img src="img/facebooklogin.png">
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide html as well?

Comment: @Edward -- sorry it is wrapped in #main.

Answer (score 0):

It tries to find `#fblogin` within `#main` and binds `onClick` to it, which I think is why it is not working (according to html you provided) because `#fblogin` is not within `#main`.

Try:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({

el : "div.social-login",

...
```